# Unmarshall inner CDATA in xml String

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, cdata

I need to unmarshall the following xml String named `retornoExtrato` in my code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extrato xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <erro>
      <codigo/>
      <descricao/>
   </erro>
   <consultaextrato>
      <header><![CDATA[SOME MULTIPLE
LINES HEADER]]></header>
      <body><![CDATA[SOME MULTIPLE
LINES BODY]]></body>
      <trailer><![CDATA[SOME MULTIPLE
LINES TRAILER]]></trailer>
   </consultaextrato>
</extrato>
```

into an `Extrato` object, here are my classes (constructors, getters and setters ommited when default)

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "extrato")
public class Extrato {
    private Erro erro;
    private ConsultaExtrato consultaExtrato;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "erro")
public class Erro {
    private String codigo;
    private String descricao;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "consultaextrato")
public class ConsultaExtrato {
    private String header;
    private String body;
    private String trailer;

    @XmlCDATA
    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    @XmlCDATA
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @XmlCDATA
    public String getTrailer() {
        return trailer;
    }
}
```

The situation is when unmarshalling:

- `Erro` always get umarshelled
- `ConsultaExtrato` is getting null

```java
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Extrato.class).createUnmarshaller();
Extrato extrato = (Extrato) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(retornoExtrato));
```

On the other hand, if I create a xml with only the `consultaextrato` tag, it gets unmarshelled ok. But it doesn't seems to work as an inner tag.

I've tried some extra jaxb annotation in all classes, none worked. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell JAXB that the XML element `<consultaextrato>`
within the `<extrato>` element corresponds to
the Java property `consultaExtrato` in your `Extrato` class.

You do this by annotating this property (or rather its getter or setter method)
with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) and giving the XML [name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#name--) there:

```
@XmlElement(name = "consultaextrato")
```

If you don't do this, then JAXB would derive the XML element name
from the Java property name (i.e. `consultaExtrato`) and thus
get no match because of the different spelling.

And by the way: The `@XmlRootElement(name = "consultaextrato")`
has an effect only if the `<consultaextrato>` is the root element
of your XML content, but not if `<consultaextrato>` is a nested
element within another element (in your case within `<extrato>`
element).

Comment: You are completely right. It worked perfectly!